# Get response from dictionary in chatbot

Tags: python, dictionary, chatbot

I'm creating a simple chatbot working with `random.choice()` of possible responses to possible comments.

I would like to know how to work with dictionaries instead of `return`. And whether this ould be more advantageous for my code:

```
def create_response(self, menss, first_message):
    if first_message == menssin ('ok'):
        return random.choice(['Ok'])
    if menss == menss in ('hi'.lower(), 'hello'.lower(), 
        return random.choice(['Hi', 'Hello', 'Helloo'])
    elif menss  == menss in ('Y?'.lower(), 'Wbu?'.lower()):
        return random.choice(['No.', 'Nop.'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def __init__(self): 
    self.inventory = [
        (['Format:', 'List', 'of', 'questions'], ['list', 'of', 'possible', 'answers']),
        (['ok'], ['Ok']),
        (['hi', 'hello'], ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Helloo']),
        (['y?', 'wbu?'], ['No.', 'Nop.']),
    ]


def create_response(self, user_message):
    for questions, answers in self.inventory:
        if user_message.lower() in questions:
            return random.choice(answers)
```

This returns `None` when the `user_message` was not found in any of the questions.

Comment: I don't understand why braces were placed } on the second line. Why didn't you put square brackets?

Comment: @Behemooth You can use them, if you like. The parentheses are for [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html). But you can use lists; it will work the same for this example.